# Store Access Token and Refresh Token in cookies

Tags: .net-core, cookies, oauth, jwt, access-token

I know I could be using OAuth, OpenID or SAML. However,  I am wondering if I could take a simpler path given that my apps are running under the same sub-domain and I have CORS properly configured.

- https://admin.mycompany.com/app1
- https://admin.mycompany.com/app2
- https://admin.mycompany.com/app3
- https://admin.mycompany.com/login (*Single Sign On*)

These apps are either built in React or server side Razor Pages with Antiforgery Token.
For these two types of apps, would it be ok storing?

- **Access Token** in a Cookie accesible from javascript (short-lived) (JWT)(<4Kb)
- **Refresh Token** in a Cookie not accesible from javascript (HttpOnly) (long-lived)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is in line with OAuth patterns. Hopefully the pointers move you forward a little, though I am not aware of factors such as the data sensitivity of your apps.

**REFRESH TOKEN**

If you store this in a cookie then use these properties:

- SameSite=strict
- HTTP Only
- Secure
- Domain=admin.mycompany.com
- Path: /login/refresh

**ACCESS TOKEN**

Do the same and use a different path if required. Avoid use of non HTTP Only cookies since malicious code in the browser could then grab tokens by reading document.cookie.

Another option is to send the RT cookie to get an access token to the browser and store it in memory - see [BFF TMI](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-bertocci-oauth2-tmi-bff/).

Note however that access tokens in the browser are discouraged since they have more risks and require more mitigations - see [this video](https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/talks/xssoauth.html).

**ENCRYPTION**

Encrypt cookies containing tokens using AES256 and a secret only known server side.

**SCOPING**

Ideally each app should redirect and get its own independent tokens, since otherwise there is a risk that an App1 user has App3 permissions - make sure your back end authorization deals with this.

Comment: How do I achieve Single Sign on for these two type of apps then?
React apps make client side API calls with the Access Token.
Razor apps make server side API calls with the Access Token too.
Therefore, I need to store the Access Token as non HttpOnly, so it is accesible server and client side.

Comment: A common way to deal with this is to provide a GET /token endpoint that the React app can use. Send the HTTP only cookie containing the access token from the browser to the server, then receive the AT in a JSON response. The React app can store the token in a memory closure, rather than it being available globally. Of course also ensure that your app does not have any XSS vulnerabilities that allow the endpoint to be abused.

Comment: But the user needs to come to the `/login/refresh` page, the browser can automatically carry the corresponding cookie, does this mean redirecting to achieve the goal

Comment: The cookie related calls can all be done via Ajax calls without impacting the user. Have a look at [this code example](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff). its OAuthClient class and the documentation linked to from the repo's README.md file.